# Is it possible to pass char* between COM objects

Tags: c++, string, delphi, unicode, com

I need to modify application that is written on Delphi and C++ and uses COM. And I've seen quite often that COM wrappers always use WideString and BSTR, even though in the end dll that is used works with plain char*. So it's impossible to communicate between COM objects without unicode strings?
Some links for further reading on the topic is very appreciated.

Comment: COM is designed to work across a network if necessary, so it really can't work with pointers at all.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use BSTR?

Comment: Can't say about Delphi, but yes, you can use char* arguments with COM objects. In-process pointers will be shared, out-of-process or across COM apartment, they will be pointers to proxies of char* (this is marshaling). For example this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu-getcommandstring uses char* pointers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan coz I need only ansi strings, and also it's more like a general question is it possible at all in COM

Comment: Wh fight the system? What's wrong with BSTR?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have two components, they communicate via COM. Both uses ansi strings. But for the communication I have to convert ansi string to BSTR and then on the other side convert BSTR back to ansi string. It's the only way?

Comment: If it were me I wouldn't be using ANSI at all. But if you have to convert, how hard can it be? It's two functions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not saying it's hard, I'm double-checking that I understood correctly that COM doesn't have other ways

Comment: Remy Lebeau posted a pretty good answer.  After seeing that you may decide that converting back and forth to BSTR is the lesser of many evils.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass around an 8-bit `char` string in COM, you can either:

- use [`SysAllocStringByteLen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstringbytelen) to create a binary [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr) that holds the raw `char` characters as-is. The receiver can then copy the `char` characters as-is from the `BSTR`.
- use [`SafeArrayCreate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycreate)/[`SafeArrayCreateVector()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycreatevector) to create a [`SAFEARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb401744(v=msdn.10)) holding `VT_UI8` elements, and then you can copy the `char` characters as-is into the array.  You can put the `SAFEARRAY` inside of a [`VARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant), if needed.
- wrap the `char` characters inside of an [`IStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream), such as from [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-createstreamonhglobal) or [`SHCreateMemStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream).